# Why is $\text{Var(}\text{min}(X, Y)) = \text{Var(}\text{max}(X, Y))$ for $X, Y \stackrel{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance

I intuitively get that there is some sort of symmetry at play that makes $\text{Var}(\text{max}(X, Y)) = \text{Var}(\text{min}(X, Y))$ for $X, Y \stackrel{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ since, generally, there is symmetry for two continuous, i.i.d random variables $A, B$ in that $P(A > B) = P(A < B)$.

What I don't quite understand is this justification:

> By symmetry of the Normal, $(X, Y)$ has the same
> distribution as $(-X, -Y)$, so $\text{Var}(\text{max}(X, Y)) = \text{Var}(\text{min}(X, Y))$. ([Source](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_8.pdf))

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/288492/161519) begins to tease this out a little, but I'm still missing *why* the fact that $-X = X$ and $-Y=Y$ means it's necessarily so that the dispersion of the minimum and maximum of two i.i.d standard normal random variables is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $\max(x, y) = -\min(-x, -y)$, you have that
$$\text{Var}(\max(X, Y)) = \text{Var}(-\min(-X, -Y))$$

But since $\text{Var}(-X) = \text{Var}(X)$, this simplifies to $\text{Var}(\min(-X, -Y)$. And then since the distribution of $X$ and $-X$ are the same, this simplifies to $\text{Var}(\min(X, -Y))$. Finally because the distribution of $Y$ and $-Y$ are the same, this simplifies to $\text{Var}(\min(X, Y))$.

In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are chosen from symmetric distributions (it doesn't necessarily have to be the same distribution for each), then $$\text{Var}(\max(X, Y)) = \text{Var}(\min(X, Y))$$

Answer (score 1):

A slight variant on @VarunVejalla's approach: let $\Phi$ denote the $\mathcal{N}(0,\,1)$ CDF so$$P(\min(X,\,Y)\le z)=1-(1-\Phi(z))^2=1-\Phi(-z)^2$$(the last $=$ uses symmetry), and $P(\max(X,\,Y)\le z)=\Phi^2(z)$. So $\min(X,\,Y)$'s distribution is that of $-\max(X,\,Y)$, whence$$\operatorname{Var}\min(X,\,Y)=\operatorname{Var}[-\max(X,\,Y)]=\operatorname{Var}\max(X,\,Y).$$

Comment: Just a little confused as I'm trying to work this out: should the inequalities in the probability functions be flipped, i.e., $P(\min(X,\,Y) \geq z)=1-(1-\Phi(z))^2=1-\Phi(-z)^2$?

Comment: @Per48edjes No,$$\begin{align}P(\min(X,\,Y)\ge z)&=P(X\ge z\land Y\ge z)\\&=(1-\Phi(z))^2\\\implies P(\min(X,\,Y)\ge z)&=1-(1-\Phi(z))^2.\end{align}$$

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong. Thanks, @J.G. -- there should be a $\leq$ sign in $P(\max(X,\,Y))=\Phi^2(z)$, though, yeah?

Comment: @Per48edjes Thanks; fixed.